# react hooks: how to handle co-dependent useCallbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

the react hook's linter likes to be strict with the DependencyList. That leads to the following broken situation where 2 event handlers depend on each other.
Since the functions are registered with `addEventListener` I know if they ever change it'll introduce a memory leak so the easy thing to do is just empty the dependency list-- but what is the *right* way to handle this while playing by the linter's rules?

```
const onMouseMove = useCallback((e) => {
  if (!isSwipe(e)) {
    onMouseUp(e)
  }
}, [onMouseUp])

const onMouseUp = useCallback((e) => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
}, [onMouseMove])
```

Comment: How are you using `onMouseUp` before it defined? Can you explain what you trying to do (the scenario)?

Comment: that's the problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How to use `onMouseUp` before its defined or how to use two callback that depends on each other?

Comment: how to handle co-dependent useCallbacks

Answer (score 4):

`useCallback` is essentially a version of `useMemo`, specialized for memoizing functions.  If two functions are co-dependent and can't be memoized separately with `useCallback`, they can be memoized together with `useMemo`:

```
const { onMouseMove, onMouseUp } = useMemo(() => {
    const onMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!isSwipe(e)) {
            onMouseUp(e)
        }
    };
    const onMouseUp = (e) => {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
    }
    return { onMouseMove, onMouseUp };
}, [/* shared deps*/]);
```

This is the general pattern I'd use to memoize functions together, and I think it's the simplest answer to the general question.  But I'm not sure, looking at the actual code here, that it's the best approach - the `removeEventListener` may not work if the `onMouseMove` is a different function than the one that was registered due to `useMemo` recalculating.  Might be more of a `useEffect` sort of use-case, in practice.

Answer (score 0):

after some research, looks like the solution for ([useCallback() invalidates too often in practice](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14099)) also fixes this.
The general idea is to memoize a function that points to a ref that points to the most recent function.

It's a dirty hack that may also cause problems in concurrent mode, but for now, it's what facebook recommends:[How to read an often-changing value from useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback)

```
const useEventCallback = (fn) => {
    const ref = useRef(fn)
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = fn
    })
    return useCallback((...args) => {
        ref.current(...args)
    }, [ref])
}

const onMouseMove = useEventCallback((e) => {
  if (!isSwipe(e)) {
    onMouseUp(e)
  }
})

const onMouseUp = useEventCallback((e) => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
})
```